# RestKit: how to change RKRequest body string from JSON to plain text?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, rest, restkit

I need to post some request with the format of body:

username=<(some user name)>&password=<(some password)>

and the response string is in JSON format.

but when I create the object mapping, the body string is:

{"username":"<(some user name)>","password":<(some password)>}

Is there a way I can change the format of request body?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out:

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURLString:[MyClass baseURL]];
RKObjectLoader *loader = [manager loaderWithResourcePath:[MyClass pathForLogin]];
[loader setHTTPBodyString:@"..."];
```